# ColdFusion 302 ISAPI interfering with other modules

Tags: coldfusion, isapi, opensso

I've got a legacy ColdFusion app that I tasked with integrating with OpenSSO using their Policy Agent. The Policy Agent is a native HTTP module that essentially acts as a filter (Not in my authentication cache? Redirect to this URL with a returnUrl specified, else, if I'm being POSTed to process the returning authentication info and let the user through).

The problem is that the main index.cfm page does a 302 redirect to the app main page (app/index.cfm). When the Policy Agent generates *it's* 302 redirect, it has a return url of `http://sameplace/index.cfm,app/index.cfm`, instead of just `http://sameplace`.

It would seem that ColdFusion's * ISAPI handler is somehow getting called, and the Policy Agent MODULE is getting confused by the already existing response headers, and tacks it on with a comma to it's own return url.

Anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: I'm guessing that part of the reason you haven't received any answers is that your question was not properly tagged. It's no longer "Cold Fusion", it's now referred to as "ColdFusion" (no space). For what it's worth, if there _were_ still a space in the name, you would tag it as "cold-fusion", not two tags "cold" and "fusion".